# Can't SSH by name on stretch; can on jessie

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, putty

I just updated my Pi0W's to stretch, from jessie, and now putty won't let me connect by name (e.g. pi@computername.local) like it used to. It does work as expected if I use the IP. But the odd thing is, I still have a jessie machine on the network, and I *can* connect to it using the above naming scheme (pi@computername works, as well). This is on my local, home network. Any thoughts?

Comment: How is the IP address for the Pi0W assigned? Is it manually set on the Pi or is it getting the IP via DHCP? Or something else? Also, what is the setting of `send host-name = gethostname();` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`?

Comment: Both Pi (the Jessie one that responds to SSH pi@PiNameA.local, and the Stretch one that doesn't) get their IP addresses via DHCP.  Are you asking if I have the "send host-name..." line?  (I do, same as your example.)  Or do you want to know what follows it ("request subnet-mask, broadcast-address...")?

The only thing I've done to the Jessie Pi is install minidlna, and Samba.  Other than that, it's vanilla.  The Stretch one is vanilla.

Comment: if you actually  "updated… to stretch, from jessie" using one of the unofficial tutorials (which are not officially supported by the Foundation) who knows - there were a number of significant changes to networking. If you try on a fresh install and have problems ask a new question. There are just too many unknowns to provide a meaningful comment.

Comment: Okay, I misspoke. I didn't update; I put a fresh image on the card.  And, now that I'm thinking about it, it was the lite image, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to connect to *"stretch"* machines with `pi@computername.local`. This is the domain from `mDNS` with autoconfigured ip addresses. To *"jessie"* machines you connect with `pi@computername`. This is the naming scheme for static ip addresses or from a dhcp server with *dyndns* and search domains. By specification `mDNS` will never autoconfigure ip addresses if it find a dhcp server on the network. Try to connect to your *"stretch"* machines with `pi@computername`.

*Update:*
To clarify it: there is an important difference between `pi@computername.local` (this will address the local domain defined by RFC3927 without using DNS) and `pi@computername` (this will use name resolution through DNS or entries in `/etc/hosts`).

Comment: Have you ACTUALLY tried this? `pi@computername.local` works perfectly on macOS and Linux - `pi@computername` DOES NOT. See [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

Comment: @Milliways I ACTUALLY read [RFC3927](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927). It tells us unter 1.9.3: *"If a host finds that an interface no longer has an operable routable addr available, the host MAY identify a usable IPv4 Link-Local addr (section 2) and assign that addr to the interface. Ways in which an operable routable addr might cease to be available on an interface include: * Removal of the addr from the interface through manual configuration * Expiration of the lease on the addr assigned through DHCP * Roaming of the host to a new network on which the addr is no longer operable."*

Comment: I spent most of my life as a Telecommunications planner, and NEVER found reading specifications a substitute for testing. The RFC is about DHCP and mentions [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)
which have NOTHING to do with [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

Comment: @Milliways *Link-local address* is part of *Zero-conf*. But that isn't the point. Have you tested to address a host with `pi@computername.local` on a network with DHCP server?

Comment: Yes All my networks use DHCP. If you had read [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
 you will see I try and encourage Pi users to use DHCP.  [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) works on ANY network segment - with the possible exception of M$ non-standard implementations - which I don't have.

Comment: @Milliways internet standards are defined by RFCs. You are right to encourage people to use DHCP but it cannot used with a link-local address at the same. This would mean that an interface has two ip addresses one from the DHCP server e.g. `192.186.1.10` and one from the special block `169.254.0.0/16` for link-local addresses and autoconfigured network name `hostname.local`. The domain `.local` is resevered for this and a DNS server must not serve it. I have never seen two ip addresses on an interface on linux running `avahi` and a dhcp client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79518/discussion-between-ingo-and-milliways).

Answer (score 1):

This "naming scheme" is due to something called [`mDNS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). If you're using a Mac, it's built in as [`Bonjour`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)); if you're on Windoze, it's either from MS' dodgy implementation of `mDNS`, or from iTunes that's been installed on Windoze. You can also install software on your RPi that will add mDNS - an app (strictly speaking a service) called [`avahi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)). Installing `avahi` should resolve your issue, and make your RPi responsive to a name such as `raspberrypi.local`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

And that's it. Let us know if you have any other issues, and we'll try to help.

Comment: I am not sure mDNS is relevant to [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) - NOTE there is NO NEED to install anything on Raspbian - [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) as been included since 2015

Comment: Okay, I just checked one of the offending Pi, with dpkg -l avahi-daemon, and it's indicating that it's already installed. That is, I haven't installed it using your commands above; it's already there. But, installed is not running, so I checked that, as well, with systemctl is-active avahi-daemon.service, and it's showing as active. I would suspect that something was wrong with my putty file...but it connects as it always has to the Jessie Pi.

Comment: @Milliways: Yep, but as he had just upgraded, it seemed the most likely.

Comment: @Brian: Couple of questions: 1. What type of host are you using (i.e. linux, windoze, mac) to make the SSH connection to your RPi, and 2. What does your DHCP server on your home network show for the stretch and jessie RPi's? By that I mean does the DHCP server recognize them by name or just by IP?

Comment: @Seamus: I am connecting to the various Pi's from a Windows 10 machine, using PuTTY 0.66. Just updated PuTTY to 0.70, 64-bit; same thing. IP addresses are not static. The DHCP server shows the correct names. The following works: pi@JessiePi.local & pi@JessiePi. And these do not: pi@StretchPi.local & pi@StretchPi. In the case of the failures, the message is: Unable to open connection to StretchPI.local gethostbyname: unknown error

Comment: Just for fun, I SSHed into each Pi, and from there was able to SSH *by name* into the other Pi using both user@name and user@name.local.  That is to say, Jessie can SSH into Stretch, and vice versa.  So why is the Windows PuTTY client choking on both naming conventions for Stretch, but not Jessie?  Probably ought to be directed to the Windows client board, but I suppose it's of interest here (if it's reproducible), as well.