# Disabling IPv6 to fix name resolution issues on LAN

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp, zero-configuration-networking

I have a conventional LAN configuration. It consists of a router/firewall/gateway running [`OPNsense`](https://opnsense.org/), and a variety of hosts - mostly Macs, RPis, Ubuntus, my WiFi APs and the usual phones and video gadgets.

In preparation for a move, I recently removed the Ethernet connection to my RPi 3B (hostname `raspberrypi3b`), and created the following `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
        ssid="MyMeshyWiFi"
        psk="**********"
}
```

Here's the `ifconfig` output for `wlan0`:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.144  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2605:a601:a82d:f500::1e11  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::fb12:4c3f:73b0:2394  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:AB:CD:EF  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 932046  bytes 55887017 (53.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1736798  bytes 2654807130 (2.4 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This worked fine initially. I simply un-plugged the Ethernet cable & now connect via WiFi. Since then however, I am having SSH connect failures for `raspberrypi3b`. Following are some details:

*After a few hours (but inevitably)* my attempted SSH connections fail:

```bsh
% ssh pi@raspberrypi3b.local

# AND ...

% ssh pi@192.168.1.144
```

Hours may pass with no response. Yet, `raspberrypi3b`'s power light is illuminated, and the green light can be observed to flash occasionally. A `reboot` of `raspberrypi3b` always resolves the issue - but only for a while. This has started since using `wlan0` exclusively. If this ever failed while using `eth0` on `raspberrypi3b`, I do not recall it.

I checked the *DHCP Leases* in the DHCP server (OPNsense firewall) while `raspberrypi3b` was *missing in action*, and found **no active lease** for it. After re-booting, `ssh pi@raspberrypi3b.local` was successful, and ***then*** an active lease was shown for `raspberrypi3b`. Perhaps even more oddly: While engaged in an active & responsive SSH session with `raspberrypi3b`, I attempted to make a second SSH connection by opening another terminal window on my Mac. I was unable to connect (as described previously) using `raspberrypi3b.local`, but ***was*** able to connect using the IP address I got from the active session?!

I have configured OPNsense to "Prefer to use IPv4 even if IPv6 is available". There is a separate DHCP server for IPv6, but it has never been enabled.

I have also checked `man avahi` & found nothing useful. `man 5 avahi.service` lists an XML *fragment* that looks interesting: `<service protocol="ipv4|ipv6|any">`, but as the default is `any`, I did not change anything.

This has turned into a much longer question than I wanted, and I've still omitted some details. Any solutions for resolving this are appreciated. In the meantime, I am going to **disable IPv6** on `raspberrypi3b` to see if that has any effect.

#### ADDENDUM:

I disabled IPv6 without any noticeable effect; i.e. `raspberrypi3b.local` & `192.168.1.144` continued to suffer connection failures.

*I reviewed my network configuration*: I am using 3 [AmpliFi WiFi routers](https://www.amplifi.com/amplifi-hd) for my APs. They are configured as a "mesh" (Ethernet backhaul), and set in "Bridge Mode" (DHCP is passed through the WiFi APs to my DHCP server/OPNsense firewall. The AmpliFi HD units were added to replace older APs early last year, but otherwise this configuration has served numerous WiFi clients flawlessly for years. This issue with `raspberrypi3b.local` is the first persistent issue I've had with a WiFi client. The unfortunate thing about the AmpliFi HD units is that their admin interface is non-existent (the web GUI has been replaced by an iPhone app designed for 15 year-olds). Yeah - they are crap in this regard, and I do **not** recommend them.

I discovered a [related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108211/internet-through-wifi-lost-after-some-time-on-pi4b-on-raspbian) here. The `syslog` for `raspberrypi3b` also showed a flurry of `bpf_send: No buffer space available` messages attributed to `dhcpcd`. Unfortunately, the answers provided there didn't fix my issue.

I made a few changes to my *default* `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file in an effort to get more relevant data. The following lines were added:

```
# My Experiments:
ipv4only
debug
logfile /home/pi/mydhcpcdlog.txt
```

Another change I made was moving `raspberrypi3b` closer to one of the AmpliFiHD APs; from approx. 12 meters to 1 meter. Maybe, instead of a "mesh" configuration, Ubiquiti has designed a ["quagmire"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quagmire) configuration? :)

As mentioned above, the `ipv4only` change did not cure the connection failures for `raspberrypi3b`. However, since physically moving `raspberrypi3b` closer to one of the APs, and adding the `debug` & `logfile` changes, the connection failures have disappeared :/  I hate it when that happens! Any ideas for a troubleshooting approach would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ipv4only or noipv6 to avoid IPv6.

I experience occasional resolution failures (only resolved by restarting routers etc).
I reserve IP in my routers, so I (usually) have predictable IP.

I "avoid" the occasional problem with scripts like the following

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to start ssh connection to Pi
# If not found use default ADDRESS
# Ian Binnie 2019-07-30
# 2021-01-17 ip4

TARGET="MilliwaysPi4.local"
ADDRESS="10.1.2.84"     # WiFi
ADDRESS2="10.1.2.74"    # Ethernet

ping -c1 $TARGET > /dev/null 2>&1
rc1=$?
if [ $rc1 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Can't ping $TARGET"
    TARGET=$ADDRESS
    ping -c1 $TARGET > /dev/null 2>&1
    rc2=$?
    if [ $rc2 -gt 0 ]; then
        TARGET=$ADDRESS2
    fi
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    USR='pi'
else
    USR=$1
fi

ssh $USR@$TARGET
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```

Comment: I wonder why it *appears* to be only with WiFi (never saw this in years of using `eth0`). I did consider reserving an IP in the router, but I'd prefer to get to the bottom of this (stubborn?).